# Dealing with powers when using the definition of a null sequence to prove if a sequence is a null

Tags: sequences-and-series

Lets say I want to use the definition of a null sequence, to show a sequence is a null sequence. For example, if I want to show that the sequence

$$
\left\{\frac{1}{n^2-3}\right\} \text{, for } n \geq 1
$$

is a null sequence using the definition of a null sequence, I would need to show that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that

$$
\left\rvert\frac{1}{n^2-3}\right\rvert < \varepsilon \text{ , for all } n \geq N
$$

Now, doing so involves doing the following rearrangment of the inequality

$$
\left\rvert\frac{1}{n^2-3}\right\rvert < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow
\left(\frac{1}{n^2-3}\right)^2 < \varepsilon^2 \Leftrightarrow
(n^2-3)^2 > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}
$$
this is where I then have a question(i'll save the question until after the example though), the next steps would be
$$
n^2-3 > \sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}} \Leftrightarrow
n^2 > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} + 3\Leftrightarrow
n > \sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon} + 3}
$$

Which means that the first statement
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{n^2-3}\right\} \text{, for } n \geq 1
$$
would hold for 
$$
n > \left[\sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon} + 3}\right]
$$

However, now to my actual question, the step 
$$
n^2-3 > \sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}}
$$
is annoying me a bit, there is situations, if n=1 inequality will only hold if we put 
$$
n^2-3 > \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}}
$$
but in the next step,
$$
n^2 > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} + 3
$$
its we are good again for all $n \geq 1$.

How should I deal with this? In the end, we are looking for a value $N$ for which the inequality holds for $n > N$. So, does this mean I don't need to worry about all possible $n$ for which the sequence is defined on?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Outline: Using Archimedean Property you can find an $N\geq3$ such that $1/N<\epsilon$. Then prove by induction that for $n\geq3:n^2-3>n$.